# Convert Merge of Multiple Arrays into One Array

Tags: javascript, angular

How can i convert this merge that produces one array forEach into One Array at the end?

```
affProd.pipe(mergeMap(
          event1 => {
            return fireProd.pipe(
              map(event2 => {
                const finalArray = [{}];
                event1.forEach((e1) =>
                event2.forEach((e2) => {
                // console.log(e1);
                  if (e1.upc.toString() === e2.affiliateUpc.toString()) {
                    this.merge2 = [{ ...e1, ...e2 }];
                  } else {
                    // return console.log('No Data');
                  }
                })
              );
              } ));
            }
        )).subscribe((x) => console.log(x));
```

the output from above

[image]

Comment: I guess it would be the easiest if you just show what you got and what you wanna get ...

Comment: What I get is the output in the  question. The picture. What I want is the objects into one array.

Comment: I tried doing a push but I couldn't get it working

Answer (score 0):

So i have answered my one question. 
The objective here is to merge two objects into one array. 
I have two objects being called from two different APIs. I wanted to merge these into one object and push the multiple merged objects into one array.

This was done using ... and brackets.

```
const finalArray = [];
return finalArray.push({...e1, ...e2});
```

I never once used the merge command to do this.